# Get all informations of a discrete random variable in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

Imagine that I build a discrete random variable in tensorflow. There is a way to get the P(X = k) and associated probabilities ?  i.e two lists [k_1 .., k_n] and [p_1,.., p_n] with p_i = P(X = k_i) ?

Answer (score 0):

How about `tfp.distributions.Categorical(logits=np.random.randn(10)).probs_parameter()`

And if you wanted it to take on values different from 0..9, you could use `tfp.distributions.FiniteDiscrete`

Comment: I'm not sure that it's work.. in fact, I'm already use a quantized distribution of continuous distribution and I want to get {X=k} and associated probabilites of my quantized tensor

Comment: Do you know the range of the support for the underlying distribution? Then you could just write quantized.log_prob(tf.range(support_min, support_max))